# What is normal page loading time?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make sure my mysql runs fast. It loads page per 0,01sec. Is it good or not?

Comment: is 0,01s too long for your to wait ?

Comment: That's way too long. I leave any website that doesn't load in 0.005 seconds or faster.

Comment: @ceejayoz: If my page doesn't load by the time I've started typing the URL I give up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

10 milliseconds is easily fast enough. The more pertinent question is, how long will pageloads take when your site has 1000x as much data in MySQL and 1000 times as many people requesting pageloads at the same time.

Ideally someone with a cold cache should be able to load your front page in under a second - 500ms and below would be a *good* time. The actual page generation portion of things shouldn't take much longer than 100ms.

Comment: Thank you for at least one answer without joking.

Comment: @hey, Surf the web. How long do you think pages like Google, Yahoo, StackOverflow take loading? Isn't your app faster than most you've surfed? Your question seems silly... 0,01ms is extremely fast and some static HTML pages take longer than that!

Comment: So? He asked "is it good or not?" and the answer is "it's good". It wasn't a silly question, it is an important consideration!

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say.... it depends on your data structures, data volumes, and the queries that you are running.... but page generation speed isn't the way to measure the efficiency of MySQL queries.